# TypeError: jQuery(...).validate is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I am bringing a dynamic html content on to another html content. This is basically an edit form html view, but when I try to validate the from, it gives me "TypeError: jQuery(...).validate is not a function" error. I am using jQuery 1.6.2 version.

```
function validate_edit_venue() {
    jQuery('#venue_edit_form').validate({
        rules: {
            venueName: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 1,
                maxlength: 50
            },
            venueDescription: {
                required: false,
                lettersonly: true,
                maxlength: 150
            },
            venueType: {
                required: true
            }

        },
        messages: {
            venueName: {
                required: "Venue name is required",
                minlength: "Minimum 1  character required",
                maxlength: "Should not exceed 50 characters"
            },
            venueDescription: {
                maxlength: "Should not exceed 150 characters"
            },
            venueType: {
                required: "Please select a venue type"
            }

        }
    });
}
```

This is my jQuery validation. I am calling this function at the jQuery edit form script. Can anyone help me with this issue? This question maybe a duplicate but most of them are due to the jQuery version issue, so I couldn't obtain a proper answer through them.

```
      jQuery('#venue_edit_save').live('click', function(){

       validate_edit_venue();

       if(jQuery("#venue_edit_form").valid())
       {
            var directory_id = jQuery(this).attr('directory_id');
            var venue_type = jQuery(this).attr('venue_type');
            var venueName = jQuery('#venue_name').val();
            var venueDescription = jQuery('#description').val();
            var venueType = jQuery('#venue_types option:selected').val();
            var venueImage = jQuery('[name="profile_image'+directory_id+'"]').val();
            jQuery.blockUI();
            jQuery.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    cache: false,
                    dataType: 'json',
                    url: baseurl+'catalog/catalog/action/venues/edit_venue',                
                    data:{'directory_id':directory_id,'venueName':venueName,'venueDescription':venueDescription,'venueType':venueType,'venueImage':venueImage},                

                    success: function(data)
                    {                    
                        if(data.status == 'success')
                        {
                        /*if(venue_type == venueType)
                        {
                            jQuery('#Venue_'+directory_id).replaceWith(data.html);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            location.reload();                              
                        }*/
                            jQuery('#Venue_'+directory_id).replaceWith(data.html);
                            show_messages(data.status,data.msg);
                            setTimeout(jQuery.unblockUI);
                            jQuery('#edit-dining-venue-block').hide();
                            location.reload();
                        } 
                        else if(data.status == 401)
                        {
                            redirect_login_timed_out();                         
                        }
                    /*else
                    {
                        show_messages(data.status,data.msg);
                        setTimeout(jQuery.unblockUI);
                        jQuery('#edit-dining-venue-block').hide();
                    }*/
                    },
                    error:function (jqXHR)
                    {
                        if(jqXHR.status == 401)
                        {
                            redirect_login_timed_out();
                        }
                        setTimeout(jQuery.unblockUI);
                    }

            }); 
       }
  });

   // Hiding the edit venue view when clicking the cancel button
   jQuery('#venue_edit_cancel').live('click', function(){

       jQuery('#edit-dining-venue-block').hide();

   });              

});
```

This is where the error occurs. This jQuery saves the edited info: while validating.

Thanks.

Comment: jQuery .validation is a plugin, do you have the .js file besides the jQuery "normal" library file?

Comment: Yes. I have added all the necessary plugins needed including the validation plugin.

Comment: Make sure that jQuery-validation is compatible with jQuery version you're using.

Comment: Please also show us how you're including your scripts.

Comment: Yes. The validation plugin is compatible with the jQuery version I'm using. Actually this error is occurring only in this dynamic html content. In other places, this error doesn't occur and the forms are validated properly. 

eg: in 'add' form, the validation is properly working, but in edit form, it's not working, instead it's giving the above mentioned error. Edit form is a dynamic html content.

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $this->config->item('js'); ?>jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>

Comment: There is no need to put `jQuery('#venue_edit_form').validate({...})` inside of another function and only called when clicked.  Since `.validate()` is the plugin's initialization, you just need to run it _once_ within the DOM ready handler, not on every click.

Comment: That's true. Even though I don't put the validation under a function and call it in the necessary button click event, I've got to check the edit form like this. if(jQuery("#venue_edit_form").valid()){..} So when I check it like that, then the error occurs as Typ'eError: jQuery(...).valid is not a function'. In addition to that, I have different forms validations inside the same script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This appears to me the case of your ajax call returning script tags.

I think what happens here is your ajax call returns DOM along with another jquery script tag which overwrites your jquery and you loose all your plugins, and other bad things happen

Comment: True. I'm including some other php files which contain the script tags in them. So if that's the reason, I may have to look for another solution if the script tags overwrite, is it?

Comment: yes, this is your problem. ajax calls should return html without script tags. you may have to create a special file for it and not reuse existing ones

Comment: I managed to solve this issue. I put jq instead jQuery and it worked. There's another js file running above my script, and in that script instead jQuery, jq has been used. So now it's working perfectly fine. Thank you for your help.